# What's an alternative to triggers when using a Jet tables in an Access Database (mdb file)?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, ms-access, triggers

I have this project that would require users to check in/out through a finger print reader [ZK SF200](http://www.zkteco.co.za/sf200.html).

The system that I am building needs to fetch new data that is added into this machine's database which unfortunately is a MS Access mdb file.
In my limited experience in MS Access databases, I managed to link this file to my MySql database table which allows me to manually do the insert from MS Access.
All I want to do now is to create some form of trigger that would add data to my MySql database when new rows are inserted into the MS Access table.

This problem would have been solved if the file type was .accdb because we can use After Insert events however it is an mbd type so those are not supported.

Any idea on how I can solve this matter ?

As a final note: I am willing to change DBMS in case MySql is the obstacle here. Would creating a linked server or doing sql server replication through mssql 2008 r2 work ?

**EDIT**: I need to insert data to MySql table because I have a trigger implemented there which does its side of logical manipulation of the data (ex: Increment the number of visits for the customer, check if customer subscription has expired or not and update the customer status accordingly)

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use VBA or macros on the Access form that appends data to linked MySQL table? Most likely you are using Access as a frontend, so use its user interface features. Forms come equipped with AfterInsert, OnOpen, BeforeChange, button OnClick, and many other control/trigger events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linking a table in MS-Access to the ODBC source is probably an answer for you. The table in MS-Access will be more like a view on the source table. Any DML operation (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) will be synced immediately with the source database. You will not need any trigger, which is not available in MS-Access (unless some VBA expert knows a solution).

The Linked table technology is default available for SQL-server, but since it uses ODBC I quess you can use it with MySQL too.

Comment: Hi Martijn, thanks for the info about MySql I will look it up. I do need to add that it's necessary that I insert data to my own table because I have a trigger ready which will do some logical modification of the data, as updated on my post.

Comment: In case of a linked table you could possibly implement the trigger in the linked table in MySQL server.

Comment: Martijn that was a great idea ! Thanks man that solved my issue.

Since the fingerprint reader inserts data to a specific table called checkinout. What I did was that I created a table with the same name and datatype in MySQL then I deleted the original table in MS Access DB and replaced it with the table I created in MySQL by linking it in MS Access.

Comment: Now all I had to do was just to implement a trigger on the MySQL side which will do the logical handling on insert.
Its kind of like cheating the system, I was pretty surprised that it actually worked.